# Why does id generate dynamically for controls in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a control, say for example:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="button"></asp:Button>
```

The actual id is "button" but during debugging while using the browsers console i can find the id as something like "ctl100_but$button". Now following are my doubts.

1.) From where does ctl100_but is generated?
2.)What is the purpose of this id?
3.)Is there a way to stop this dynamic generation?

Thanks.

Comment: See this article for further info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs. You can use `ClientIDMode=Static` in server controls you want to use static `ClientID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 & 2. This is generated in the backend by asp.net when it converts your asp.net code into html code which could be understood by the browsers. The only purpose is to avoid duplicate IDs when we use repeaters or gridview because in these cases we design Item template with same ID and when gridview or repeater is rendered then there are multiple items. So Asp.Net uses this dynamic Id generation. Gridview and repeater are just few examples, there are many more such controls.

3. You can always set it to be same as you have specified by adding ClientIDMode="static" in your code. So your above code will look like :

   ```
   <asp:Button runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" id="button"></asp:Button>
   ```

Making it static will not affect anything, as long as there are no duplicate ids.

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no specific purpose for these"? And making it static surely will affect things. Otherwise it wouldn't exist.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen: Now I understood things.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen The only purpose is to avoid duplicate IDs when we use repeaters or gridview because in these cases we design Item template with same ID and when gridview or repeater is rendered then there are multiple items. So Asp.Net uses this dynamic Id generation. Hope you got it?

Comment: @AbhishekMaurya I know why it is. I’d rather you edit the answer and actually include this and not say there isn’t a specific purpose when there actually are. And repeaters etc aren’t the only things this is needed for. That’s why it’s default.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is sort of naming convention of framework and how framework works in it's own way.
Please see details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx